# Database field with predefined possible values

Tags: java, database

I followed this complete beginners tutorial:
http://www.homeandlearn.co.uk/java/databases_and_java_forms.html and now have a question:

I want to have a field that only can hold a limited number of predefined values?

Comment: Traditionally with databases, you only get *one* default value.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a CHECK Constraint:

```
CREATE TABLE Persons (
    ID int NOT NULL,
    LastName varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    FirstName varchar(255),
    DegreeLevel varchar(30) CHECK (DegreeLevel IN ('Msc.', 'Phd.', 'Without studies'))
);
```

Take a look:
https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_check.asp